# Installing java on ubuntu... what is my java home?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I use the below to install java on Ubuntu.  What should my JAVA_HOME be:

```
sudo apt-get -y install openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-6-jre
```

e.g. JAVE_HOME=?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is how it is set up on mine:

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26`

You can check using the command

`whereis jvm`

Answer (score 2):

do the command:

*which java*

probably will return
 */usr/bin/java* that is a link to */etc/alternatives/java* which is another link to (probably) */usr/local/jvm/java-6-sub/jre/bin/java* , so, your *JAVA_HOME* is/should be set to */usr/local/jvm/java-6-sub/jre*

Answer (score 1):

Try `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/`. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `/usr/lib/jvm` it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Type : "echo $JAV" and then hit tab for auto-complete. Then hit enter.
If the path variable does not exist use : "whereis java" or "find / -iname "java" 2>/dev/null"